# Android online database question

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, network-programming

I am making an app similar to My Tracks. It will track where you have been and give you odometer readings and whatnot. I have it set up so that it records everything in a SQLite database for the Android app, but I also want to allow the users to upload their trails to a database and search for other trails (by city and state, by user, etc).

I've done countless searches on Google for this, but cannot find any good examples. What do I need to be able to allow them to upload their trail? Obviously I need some type of client-server communication, but I am confused on how to do this. Is it possible to set up a server on my laptop without paying for service from Go-Daddy or other web hosting companies? I do not know enough about networking to know how to go about this. I believe I just need to be able to communicate with a PHP server to query a SQL database, but I have no idea how to set this up on my machine and allow my Android app to communicate with it.

Also, I would like the user to be able to attach picture(s) to their trails that they record. I know a little about client-server communication when it just comes to text (the client sending a text message to the server, then the server analyzing the command and sending back an appropriate text response), but I have no idea on uploading a picture (or file in general) to the server. I'm guessing some type of FTP protocol would be needed, but I cannot find any good tutorials on this either through Google.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

run a web server.

do POST file upload with
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Then  use $_FILES on the server.

http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/HttpUpload

Comment: My main question is how do I set up a web server on my computer and what URL would I then supply in the Android app to be able to communicate with this server?

Comment: do this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP
then put someScript.php in /var/www/ (or whatever the root will be) and do your thing. It will be available at http://<your-ip>:<port>/someScript.php. If you've got a dynamic ip, us http://www.no-ip.com/ or some kind of dynamic dns provider. Or just pay the $10 a month and get shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you obviously have no or little experience in running a web server you should:

a) really read into it before trying to create a reasonably reliable server at home

b) rent some server space

Do some google-ing, or post more detailed question here.

As far as sending data is concerned, you can use the solution miki has posted or implement some sort of API